# Tools for creating a "test" like environment on a development database

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, testing, oracle11g

We have an Oracle Enterprise database in production and another instance that we use as both a QA and Development database.  QA has requested that they be given separate schemas within the database so they can test applications isolated from changes made by developers.  For an example, say the schema used in development and the one that will be used in production is called APP_OWNER and APP_OWNER could contain tables that have FK references to tables in other schemas, say in BASE_OWNER.  The idea would be to create a QA_APP_OWNER schema and to pull over the production data into that schema as well as pulling any BASE_OWNER tables referenced into the QA_APP_OWNER schema as well.  A simplified illustration would be:

```
Prod Setup:
----------------
BASE_OWNER.users
APP_OWNER.users (synonym to BASE_OWNER.users)
APP_OWNER.audit_users with FK to BASE_OWNER.users

QA Setup:
----------------
QA_APP_OWNER.users  (copied data from prod)
QA_APP_OWNER.audit_users (FK to APP_OWNER.users)
```

This should be possible as we do not write code/SQL including schemas. (i.e we create schema based synonyms for tables outside the schema the application is running in)

My question is, are there good tools for easily creating such a QA_APP_OWNER schema?  I'm aware of the FROMUSER TOUSER options of export, but If I remember correctly this will move an entire schema to another schema but it won't get me all the way to where I want to be b/c I need to change the references on the FKs.  I'm unaware of a way short of exporting the DDL, manually changing it, and then importing the data manually.  This is not an attractive option as many references are to tables that also reference other tables and the APP_OWNER schema has a plethora of tables itself.  My fear is the more manual this is, the more likely-hood of a mistake that will allow something being tested to break when moved to the production environment.  A nice solution would be to have licenses for both a dev and a qa instance of Oracle, but I have been told "it isn't in the budget" to do so.

Comment: Check with your Oracle rep. With processor licensing you should be able to run as many instances on your licensed server as you like.

Comment: We don't have the option of running another instance.

Comment: 'isolated from changes made by developers' to the schema, perhaps, but not from database changes (patching, init parameters, etc.). Having a separate QA environment is a good, if not essential, idea, but doing it like this doesn't seem to gain you (them) much. It would also maybe be preferable to exactly duplicate the productions schemas and synonyms in QA anyway to spot potential problems with new objects before go-live. (And if you can't have a new QA instance, can you have a new dev instance instead? *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a long shot, but will the `impdp` `REMAP_SCHEMA` option handle foreign keys in other schemas? I know there are some things it doesn't attempt to deal with but don't recall this scenario being mentioned - possibly just because it's unusual though.

Potentially you could do a single `expdp` of all the schemas, and an `impdp` remapping them all to `QA_APP_OWNER` in one go. Clearly this isn't something I've ever tried...

Comment: I'll have a look and see if it helps.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This worked great.  Using REMAP_SCHEMA and REMAP_TABLESPACE I was able to generate a QA_x tablespace with all the necessary tables sourced from other schemas.  I still feel that doing a separate database would be a much better solution, this makes the alternative at least somewhat manageable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it.. Setup separate QA and Development databases. What you are wanting just isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my sanity.  This is exactly my stance on the matter, yet I'm being told to do it anyway.  I see how creating a QA_X schema fixes the problem of having QA and developers step on each other, but the work involved to get there and the fact that you're testing something using different database scripts than what you're going to execute to create the env. in production seems like a poor solution and one that will bring more problems.  The medicine is worse than the disease.